# Get custom getter property into QueryBuilder object?

Tags: symfony, query-builder, dql

I have the following QueryBuilder snippet working as expected:

```
$restaurants = $qb->select('r.id, r.name, r.addressGpsLat, r.addressGpsLng, r.addressZip, r.addressCity')
           ->from('BackendBundle:Restaurant', 'r')
           ->orderBy('r.name', 'ASC');
```

In our  Restaurant entity we calculate ratings based on a relation, which looks like this:

```
public function getRating()
{
    $rating = 0;
    $votes = count($this->votes);

    foreach ($this->votes as $vote) {
        $rating += $vote->getRating();
    }

    if ($votes == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    return number_format(($rating / $votes), 2, ',', '.');
}
```

So my question: is there a way I get the result of the getRating() property into my QueryBuilder object? We need it to be a seperate attribute in our JSON response. E.g. `{ …, "rating":2.2, …}`

Any advice on this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you currently using [jms serializer bundle](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer)? If so, you might want to use [@VirtualProperty](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#virtualproperty). If not, you might want to use it. ;)

Comment: We use the symfony2 serializer bundle. Switching is not an option…

Comment: Well, I read the docs and can't find a way. Maybe setting a group to the function could work. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#attributes-groups